# How can I install multiple versions of llvm libc++ on the same computer at the same time (ubuntu)?

Tags: apt, c++

I've tried the obvious:

```
apt-get install -y clang++-7 libc++abi-7-dev libc++-7-dev
apt-get install -y clang++-8 libc++-8-dev libc++abi-8-dev
apt-get install -y clang++-9 libc++-9-dev libc++abi-9-dev
apt-get install -y clang++-10 libc++-10-dev libc++abi-10-dev
```

No problem with multiple versions of clang++. But each version of libc++ appears to uninstall the previous.

When I try:

```
apt-get install libc++abi-7-dev libc++-7-dev  libc++abi-8-dev libc++-8-dev libc++-9-dev libc++abi-9-dev libc++-10-dev libc++abi-10-dev
```

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc++-10-dev : Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev
 libc++-7-dev : Depends: libc++1-7 (= 1:7.0.1-12) but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev
 libc++-8-dev : Depends: libc++1-8 (= 1:8.0.1-9) but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev
 libc++-9-dev : Depends: libc++1-9 (= 1:9.0.1-11ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev
 libc++abi-10-dev : Conflicts: libc++abi-x.y-dev
 libc++abi-7-dev : Depends: libc++abi1-7 (= 1:7.0.1-12) but it is not going to be installed
                   Conflicts: libc++abi-x.y-dev
 libc++abi-8-dev : Depends: libc++abi1-8 (= 1:8.0.1-9) but it is not going to be installed
                   Conflicts: libc++abi-x.y-dev
 libc++abi-9-dev : Depends: libc++abi1-9 (= 1:9.0.1-11ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Conflicts: libc++abi-x.y-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I'm trying this on ubuntu 20.04, but I've tried similar on past versions of Ubuntu, and run into basically the same problem.

Comment: Note this same 'misfeature' exists in Ubuntu 20.10